Expand product of sums in sympy by introducing new dummy indices
I want to use sympy to simplify some expressions which contain products of sums, this will require expanding out the products and cancelling equal terms.
i, j, k, l = symbols('i, j, k, l', cls=Dummy)
A = IndexedBase('A')
N = symbols('N', integer=True, positive=True)
s = Sum(A[i]*A[j], (i, 1, N), (j, 1, N))
expr = s**2

Running expr.doit(), expr.expand() or expr.simplify() will leave the expression unchanged.
The expression appears as

How can I expand the product and introduce dummy indices to turn the expression into the following?

Asked on stackoverlfow with no response.

Multiplication distributes over addition;
$$\sum_{ij}A_iA_j = \sum_i\left(\sum_jA_iA_j\right) = \sum_i\left(A_i\sum_jA_j\right)= \left(\sum_iA_i\right)\left(\sum_jA_j\right) = \left(\sum_iA_i\right)^2$$
The same thing works for your four index sum:
$$\sum_{ijkl}A_iA_jA_kA_l = \left(\sum_iA_i\right)^4 = \left(\sum_{ij}A_iA_j\right)^2$$
Personally, I would consider $\left(\sum_iA_i\right)^4$ to be the simplest version, and the easiest to calculate, but I do not know what you are doing.
